# How to increase an array index in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, html-table

I created a JavaScript function where I defined an array and appended the array values to an HTML table, but I don't know how to increase the array index dynamically.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="time">Time Stamp</th>
      <th id="tmpr">Temperature</th>
      <th id="crrt">Current</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="abc">
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function storetime() {
 var tim = [
  ["11:34:4", 30, 31],
  ["11:34:5", 34, 35],
  ["11:34:6", 37, 39]
 ];
 
 $.each(tim, function(i, val) {
  $("#abc").append(
   `<tr><td> (` + val[0] + `)</td> <td> (` + val[1] + `)</td></tr>`
  );
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what `id` do u mean?

Comment: Search online: 'javascript add array element'

Comment: What is the output you are expecting in the table?

Comment: look for `Array.prototype.push()` (cfr. https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solutions is create a string of table body elements and using a function html to render the string on screen.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function storetime() {
        let html = '';
        var tim = [['11:34:4', 30, 31], ['11:34:5', 34, 35], ['11:34:6', 37, 39]];
        $.each(tim, function (i, val) {
            html += `<tr><td> (${val[0]})</td> <td> (${val[1]})</td></tr>`;
        });
        $('#abc').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

There are more solutions, search about createElement function and appendChild function.